# server side data in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, request

I am trying to make GET request with node request module. I am making request to the coursera api. As the api is using CORS. Therefore I have to make server side requests.
But the thing is how to use this data in index.html to dynamically fill data.

As here I am getting the whole data to the file. Is there any way to give this data to the Angular controller.

In brief, I want to use data from coursera api inside my angular app. I have used client side so know less about server side.

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");
request("https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1").pipe(fs.createWriteStream("data.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can get the data into index.html:

1) Use Jade (Pug) Render:

```
var COURSERA_DATA = null;
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!COURSERA_DATA) {
        request("https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1",function(err,res,body) {
             COURSERA_DATA = body; /* verify first */
             res.render('index', {data: COURSERA_DATA});
        });
    } else {
       res.render('index', {data: COURSERA_DATA});
    }
});
```

and then in index.html:

```
script(text/javascript).
  var theDATA = !{JSON.stringify(data)}; // inserted by jade
```

and finally in angular1

```
app.controller('AnyController',function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = theDATA; 
});
```

2) Client request to URL which is proxied to coursera's API

```
router.get('/coursera', function (req, res) {
    request("https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1").pipe(res);
}
```

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Why the problem to consume data right in Angular? Something like:

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getCursera = function() {            
        $http({
            url: "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1",
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).success(function(data) {                
            $scope.jsonResponse = data;               
        }).error(function(err) {                
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
});
```

If Coursera allow Cross Domain this it's works. The JSON response will be setted at the scope, such that you be able to show in view or do anything.

Comment: Coursera do not allow cross origin requests. Thats why the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement a simple api to send the response back to your controller like this.. 
In the server side .. (Demo)

```
var request = require('request');

router.get('/coursera', function (req, res,next) {

request.get(
    'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1',
    { json: { key: 'value' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send(body); //response from coursera
            // if you are using this as middleware write next()
        }else {
            res.send(new Error("Error while connecting to coursera"));
             // if you are using this as middleware write next(err)
    }
);
}
```

And in the angular controller ..

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getCoursera = function() {            
        $http({
            url: "baseURL/coursera",
            method: "GET",
        }).success(function(data) {                
            $scope.data = data;               
        }).error(function(err) {                
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
});
```